# Running loop over documents in python

Tags: python, csv

I've got one folder on my desktop called 'companyfollowerstweets' which contains 91 folders, each called 'followerstweets(company name)', which all contain 200 csv files, each containing the most recent Tweets of a follower of that Company on Twitter. I'm performing sentiment analysis on the first 200 rows containting Tweets of each of the 200 followers per company, of which the results are being added to one list which eventually gives me one outcome per company; the percentage of negative Tweets and Positive Tweets of all 40,000 Tweets (200 Tweets for each of 200 followers). Hope this makes sense. Right now I have only managed to run a loop over those 200 csv files per folder, where I manually enter the company's name each time. However, I want that to run over each of those 91 folders without me having to enter the company name. Here's my code:

```
import nltk
import csv
import sklearn
import nltk, string, numpy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
columns = defaultdict(list)
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import math
import sentiment_mod as s
import glob
import itertools

lijst = glob.glob('companyfollowerstweets/followerstweetsCisco/*.csv')
tweets1 = []
sent1 = []
print(lijst[0])
for item in lijst:
    stopwords_set = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    with open(item, encoding = 'latin-1') as d:
        reader1=csv.reader(d)
        next(reader1)
        for row in itertools.islice(reader1,200):
            tweets1.extend([row[2]])
        words_cleaned = [" ".join([words for words in sentence.split() if 'http' not in words and not words.startswith('@')]) for sentence in tweets1]
        words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in words_cleaned]
        words_without_stopwords = [word for word in words_filtered if not word in stopwords_set]
    tweets1 = words_without_stopwords
    tweets1 = list(filter(None, tweets1))


for d in tweets1:
    new1 = s.sentiment(d)
    sent1.extend(new1)
    total1 = len(sent1)/2
    neg_percentage1 = (sent1.count("neg")/total1)*100
    pos_percentage1 = (sent1.count("pos")/total1)*100

res = sum(sent1[1::2])/total1
low = min(sent1[1::2])
high = max(sent1[1::2])

print("% of negative Tweets:", neg_percentage1)
print("% of positive Tweets:", pos_percentage1)
print("Total number of Tweets:", total1)
print("Average confidence:", res)
print("min confidence:", low)
print("max confidence:", high)
```

This specific example is for the company 'Cisco' as you can see. How do I keep this code running for every one of the 91 folders like this one?

Comment: So you're looking for something like `os.walk()`?

Comment: @anishtain4  I'm not sure, I've tried the os module but I seem to be doing something wrong there too

Comment: You are iterating over file(s) already. Why not start your iteration as an outer loop for each corp directory, with the inner loop similar to what you have here. You can extract the name of the current corp for reporting purposes from the current folder name.

Comment: @jdv I've tried that, I think I'm having trouble with the company names. when starting my iteration as an outer loop for each corp directory, how do I do that without having to input the company name for each folder? Not sure if I'm making sense

Comment: Extract the company name from the current folder name in some manner. If you have a pattern like the name always starts with an uppercase char you can make a pattern to extract that using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk()` on your current directory (`os.getcwd()`) is what you want. That will recursively iterate over everything in your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested glob like this:

```
from glob import glob
[glob(i+'/*.csv') for i in glob('companyfollowerstweets/followerstweets*')]
```

This will return a list of lists (list of tweets for each company).

Note that this won't have any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do two loops or use `os.walk`, the latter is cleaner:

```
import os
company_results={}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('companyfollowerstweets'):
    if len(dirs)==0:
        results=do_analysis(files)
        company_results[root]=results
```

I suggest to put all your analysis in a function, much cleaner code. Then you can get a dictionary of all the results with the above code.